# No tests found for given includes

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

build.gradle:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        showStandardStreams = true // to show System.out.println in tests
    }
}
```

Unit test

```
package com.myproject.m2document
    @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS) // as result remove static for method "BeforeAll/AfterAll"
    internal class M2DocumentManagerTest {
        private val INCORRECT_LENGTH = 800
        private val FILE_INCORRECT_LENGTH_800 = "ABS_to_M2CM_incorrect_length_$INCORRECT_LENGTH.txt"
        private lateinit var m2DocumentManager: M2DocumentManager
        private lateinit var m2Parser: M2Parser
    
        @Test
        fun `Success read text file from test resources folder`() {
            javaClass.classLoader.getResource(FILE_INCORRECT_LENGTH_800)?.let {
                val file = File(it.file)
    
                val absolutePath = file.absolutePath
                assertThat(absolutePath.endsWith("/$FILE_INCORRECT_LENGTH_800"))
            }
        }
    
    }
```

I success run unit test by IntellIJ IDEA.

Nice. But when I try to run it in terminal like this:

```
 ./gradlew test --tests com.myproject.m2document.M2DocumentManagerTest
```

I get error:

```
> Task :app:compileKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileTestKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:test'.
>No tests found for given includes: [com.myproject.m2document.M2DocumentManagerTest](--tests filter

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 601ms
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Comment: Gradle report says "> No tests found for given includes: **com.myproject.M2DocumentManagerTest**" but the command has " --tests **com.myproject.m2document.M2DocumentManagerTest**" Is the fully qualified name of M2DocumentManagerTest correct?

Comment: @ocos I was updated my post

Comment: You may compare your command with Android Studio's exact gradle run command. `Android Studio > Run > Edit Configurations > M2DocumentManagerTest`.